# Telegram Inline Keyboard - How to add buttons to the new row in Telegram bot using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, api, telegram

I work with Powershell and try to create a Telegram Bot.
Could somebody advise me please on how can I create an Inline Keyboard Button on the new row?
So, for example, I need to have two buttons on the first row and third button on the second row.
Like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpQIb.png)

Here is a part of my code where I create buttons. It's working fine and all of them appears on one row.

```
$buttonsubcheck = @{ "text" = "Check status"; callback_data = "substatus" }
$buttonsubtrial = @{ "text" = "Request trial"; callback_data = "subtrial" }
$buttonsubback = @{ "text" = "Back"; callback_data = "back" }
$buttonssub = ($buttonsubcheck, $buttonsubtrial, $buttonsubback)

$buttonsubscription = @{"inline_keyboard" = @(, $buttonssub) } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
```

So, in my case I need to move $buttonsubback button to the second row.

Tried Googling but didn't found solutions or any advises for Powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The corrected code below. Maybe it will help to smbd.

```
$buttonsubscription = @()
$buttonsubcheck = @{ "text" = "Check status"; callback_data = "substatus" }
$buttonsubtrial = @{ "text" = "Request trial"; callback_data = "subtrial" }
$buttonsubback = @{ "text" = "Back"; callback_data = "back" }
$row1 = @($buttonsubcheck, $buttonsubtrial)
$row2 = @($buttonsubback)
$buttonssub = ($row1, $row2)
$buttonsubscription = @{"inline_keyboard" =  $buttonssub } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```